# python ProcessPoolExecutor do not work when in function

Tags: python, multiprocessing

python ProcessPoolExecutor works in command lines but not running after adding to a function

it is working like this

```py
from concurrent import futures

def multi_process(func, paras, threads):
    with futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=threads) as pool:
        res = pool.map(func, paras, chunksize=threads)
    return list(res)
p = multi_process(func,paras,threads)
```

but not working at all as below

```py
def upper(paras,threads):
    def func:
        some func
    def multi_process(func, paras, threads):
        with futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=threads) as pool:
            res = pool.map(func, paras, chunksize=threads)
        return list(res)
    p = multi_process(func,paras,threads)
    return p
p = upper(paras,threads)
```

no warning or error but without any response for a long time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your do get an error. Its.

```
AttributeError: Can't pickle local object 'upper.<locals>.func'.
```

The reason is for multiprocessing to work it needs the function to be defined at the global level.

To achieve what you want you can do the following:

```
from concurrent import futures

# Has to be a global function
def func(para):
    print(para)


def upper(paras,threads):
    # This cannot be a local function.
    #def func(para):
    #    print(para)
    def multi_process(func, paras, threads):
        with futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=threads) as pool:
            res = pool.map(func, paras, chunksize=threads)
        return list(res)
    p = multi_process(func, paras, threads)
    return p

paras = [1, 2, 3]
threads = 3
p = upper(paras,threads)
```

Comment: Thanks so much, it really works now, it acturally has no responce or throw any error, maybe for the code is excuted in jupyter notebook.

Comment: yes that would be the reason for you not seeing any errors. If this answered your question please mark it as answered which would help other users who view this question.